# Got 'TypeError: string indices must be integers' comparing protein sequences

Tags: python, list, bioinformatics

How can I return the list in alphabets?

I have sequence translator, and a python code that reads both dna and protein sequence. The code reads the dna sequence and translate it to protein sequence, reads the protein sequence, compares it with the translated protein sequence and prints out a list of the protein sequence that exist in the read protein sequence. How can I print a list of the protein that exist in both of them?

```
def translate_codon(cod):
    """Translates a codon into an aminoacid using an internal dictionary with the standard genetic code."""
    tc = {"GCT":"A", "GCC":"A", "GCA":"A", "GCG":"A",
          "TGT":"C", "TGC":"C",
          "GAT":"D", "GAC":"D",
          "GAA":"E", "GAG":"E",
          "TTT":"F", "TTC":"F",
          "GGT":"G", "GGC":"G", "GGA":"G", "GGG":"G",
          "CAT":"H", "CAC":"H",
          "ATA":"I", "ATT":"I", "ATC":"I",
          "AAA":"K", "AAG":"K",
          "TTA":"L", "TTG":"L", "CTT":"L", "CTC":"L", "CTA":"L", "CTG":"L",
          "ATG":"M", "AAT":"N", "AAC":"N",
          "CCT":"P", "CCC":"P", "CCA":"P", "CCG":"P",
          "CAA":"Q", "CAG":"Q",
          "CGT":"R", "CGC":"R", "CGA":"R", "CGG":"R", "AGA":"R", "AGG":"R",
          "TCT":"S", "TCC":"S", "TCA":"S", "TCG":"S", "AGT":"S", "AGC":"S",
          "ACT":"T", "ACC":"T", "ACA":"T", "ACG":"T",
          "GTT":"V", "GTC":"V", "GTA":"V", "GTG":"V",
          "TGG":"W",
          "TAT":"Y", "TAC":"Y",
          "TAA":"_", "TAG":"_", "TGA":"_"}
    if cod in tc:
        return tc[cod]
    else:
        return '-1'


def seq_prot(dna_seq, ab):
    seqm = dna_seq.upper()
    prot = ab.upper()
    seq_aa = ''
    for pos in range(0, len(seqm)-2,3):
        cod = seqm[pos:pos+3]
        seq_aa += translate_codon(cod)
    for p in seq_aa:
        if p in prot:
            seq_aa[p] += 1
        else:
            seq_aa = p

    return seq_aa

dna_seq = "ACCCCTGTGACATACCTTTATGTTGCCTCGGCGGATCAGCCCGCGCCCC"
ab = 'TLYPAP'

print("The protein sequence are :",seq_prot(dna_seq, ab))
```

The protein sequence are : TYPP

Comment: Welcome to the site. It would be very helpful to have a full example with the inputs and desired new output. Also, you will want to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is broken as it treats `seq_aa` as if it's both a `str` and a `dict`.  Let's add an actual dictionary to collect your results:

```
def seq_prot(dna_seq, ab):
    sequence = dna_seq.upper()
    protein = ab.upper()
    matches = {}

    for position in range(0, len(sequence), 3):
        codon = sequence[position: position + 3]
        aa = translate_codon(codon)

        if aa in protein:
            if aa in matches:
                matches[aa] += 1
            else:
                matches[aa] = 1

    return matches

dna_seq = "ACCCCTGTGACATACCTTTATGTTGCCTCGGCGGATCAGCCCGCGCCCC"
ab = 'TLYPAP'

print("The protein sequence matches are :", seq_prot(dna_seq, ab))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The protein sequence matches are : {'T': 2, 'P': 3, 'Y': 2, 'L': 1, 'A': 3}
```

From which you can extract proteins by using `.keys()` on the returned `dict`.  If you want the letters multiplied by the values, you can use multiply (*) as a repetition operator.  However, any sense of *order* has been lost--we're just dealing with *existence*.  If you want to preserve order, we have to go about it differently.

Comment: Thank you @cdlane for your help. Actually i want matched proteins to be printed as a list not as a dictionary. the matches will be a list (matches = '') not a dictionary (matches = {}). now my challenge is how to compute the output to print as a list. I know that mathes[aa] += 1 is a dictionary, but how do i print it as a list not a dictionary.